# gnome-keyring/pinentry gpg key password saved indefinitely after ubuntu 15.10 upgrade

Tags: gnome, password, 15.10, gnupg, gnome-keyring

After upgrading to ubuntu 15.10, the password prompt for gpg keys has changed to a program called pinentry. The pinentry prompt provides a text field for the passphrase, as well as a checkbox for "Save in password manager".

If I do not check the checkbox to "Save in password manager", then I will be prompted for my password every time I want to use my gpg key to decrypt something, which is annoying.

If I do check the checkbox, then pinentry/gnome-keyring saves my password indefinitely (across reboots), which is unacceptable from a security perspective.

Once saved, I can remove the gpg password by going to the "Keys and Passwords" gnome gui app and removing it under "Login", but I'd rather not have to remember do this manually.

In gsettings, the value of the key `desktop.gnome.crypto.cache.gpg-cache-method` is already set to `session`, but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Does anyone know how to make gnome-keyring or pinentry only save gpg password for the current login session?

Answer (score 4):

You can control the gpg-agent's password caching behavior with `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`. The relevant [gpg-agent options](https://gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Options.html#option%20%2D%2Doptions) are `default-cache-ttl` (max idle time in seconds) and `max-cache-ttl` (max time before expiry even if under active use.) The format is simply `option_name option_value`. E.g.

```
# This is a comment
default-cache-ttl 600
max-cache-ttl 7200
```

Once edited, you can force reload of the configuration with `gpgconf --reload gpg-agent`.

Caveat lector: tested on 16.04, not 15.10.

Comment: You can also set the option `no-allow-external-cache`. Then "Save in password manager" won't show up anymore, and only gpg-agent is used for caching. The password is not saved to the system keyring or even the disk at all.